# How to open windows window from gnuplot cmd

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, gnuplot

I'm trying to force GNUplot plot in windows terminal when I invoke it from CLI.

What exactly I want:

<kbd>WIN + R</kbd>
`gnuplot` `set term windows` (gnuplot when invoked from windows CMD doesn't know this type of term) `plot data.temp` and plot appears in separate windows window.

How can I achieve that or similar result?